# What does the colon mean in :name when using php bindParam

Tags: php, pdo

The PHP manual has this example for the PDO bindParam statement:

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

Does the `:` colon just mean that `:colour` is a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That maps to the named placeholder in the query. It is not required for the binding, the driver will auto-added it if not present.

In your code you have

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
                     ^^^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^^
```

The driver reads anything with the `:` and trailing text as a placeholder. It then swaps that content with the value being bound, escapes all special characters, and quotes the string.

So then your `bindparam` has

`:calories` and `:colour` which match up to each of those. Let's say `$calories` had `o'brien`. When the query went to the DB it would be:

```
SELECT name, colour, calories
FROM fruit
WHERE calories < 'o\'brien'
```

PDO also supports unnamed placeholders which are just question marks `?`. You bind these by position.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
        FROM fruit
        WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
```

and then use a `1` because it is the first placeholder.

```
$sth->bindParam(1, $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Additionally you can just pass all values to the `execute` function as an array and it will do the binding as well.

Regardless of `bindparam` or `execute` binding you have to address the binding by how you use it in the query. Unnamed is positional, named is by name.

Comment: Sorry, that answer is over my head.  Is, for example `colour` the named placeholder?  Are the two references to `colour` (with and without the colon) refering to the same object?

Comment: My example doesn't really make sense because a string being `<` something isn't the best but hopefully that demonstrates how it works.

Answer (score 0):

**parameter**

Parameter identifier. For a prepared statement using named placeholders, this will be a parameter name of the form :name. For a prepared statement using question mark placeholders, this will be the 1-indexed position of the parameter.

**variable**

Name of the PHP variable to bind to the SQL statement parameter.

see docs here for reference http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) 
VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email)");
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);

// insert a row
$firstname = "John";
$lastname = "Doe";
$email = "john@example.com";
$stmt->execute();
```